# Excel VBA: How to avoid the creation of links back to the ".xlsm" file on the ".xlsx" file, when copying a range from ".xlsm file to a ".xlsx" file?

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, copy-paste

When copying a range of cells from an Excel ".xlsm" to another Excel ".xlsx" file, I get a link to the ".xlsm" file that I can see in the "workbook links" in the ".xlsx" file.

Do anyone know the reason and how to avoid this behavior?

I've tried the following:

```
With ThisWorkbook
    lRow = .Sheets("name1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    With .Sheets("name1")
        .Range("A2:F" & lRow).Copy
        wb.Sheets("name1").Range("A2").PasteSpecial Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, _
                 NoHTMLFormatting:=True
    End With
    
    With .Sheets("name2")
        .Range(.Cells(1, 5), .Cells(37, lCol)).Copy Destination:=wb.Sheets("name2").Range("E1")
    End With
End With
```

And got: `Runtime error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error`

Comment: This does not happen because of xlsm and xlsx files. Easy to test - create a brand new, clean book1.xlsm and book2.xlsx, and copy some ranges - do you get a link? Or, copy your problem ranges to another xlsm file - do you still get a link? The cause is probably what is in the ranges you are copying - tables? names?

Comment: Thanks, Kevin. I thought that it does not have to do with the extension of the file. However as it was happening while using this configuration, I decided to inform the exact environment used.
I do not use tables nor named ranges in the source file. Also I do not copy the graphs  or figures from the source file. 
Do you think that there is come possible benefit by using the PasteSpecial as a possible solution?

Comment: One additional info: the copy/paste between workbooks pastes formulas and values but not formats.

Comment: I tried the following:
`With ThisWorkbook
lRow = .Sheets("name1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
With .Sheets("name1")
.Range("A2:F" & lRow).Copy
wb.Sheets("name1").Range("A2").PasteSpecial Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, _ NoHTMLFormatting:=True
End With
With .Sheets("name2")
.Range(.Cells(1, 5), .Cells(37, lCol)).Copy Destination:=wb.Sheets("name2").Range("E1")
End With
End With `

And got: 
Runtime error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

Any suggestion, please.

Comment: The error above happened at the line:
`wb.Sheets("Baseline").Range("A2").PasteSpecial Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, NoHTMLFormatting:=True

Comment: This question is becoming unclear. Are you still having an issue with links, or are you now just having issue with VBA errors? The new code you have added looks like code for copying from a website to Excel, it won't work if you are copying from a range to a range. What are `wb` and `lCol`? Might be better to open new questions with one issue at a time and share all the code you are using.

Comment: @Kevin. Thanks for you feedback. You are right the question is unclear. Sorry. I decided for a different approach an this question makes no sense any longer.